# Connect points by a line

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, shapefile, line, points-to-line

I have a .shp with points which have unique IDs based on which I want to connect them. 
When I run the code, it creates empty line layers without geometry.

```
layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName("shap")[0]
features = layer.getFeatures()
hodList=[]
for feat in features:
    ids=feat['shape_id']
    hodList.append(ids)
unikatniId=list(set(hodList))

for i in unikatniId:
    expression = ('"shape_id" LIKE \'%s%s\''%(i,'%'))
    request = QgsFeatureRequest().setFilterExpression(expression)
    PointList = []
    v_layer = QgsVectorLayer("LineString?crs=epsg:4326", "line", "memory")
    pr = v_layer.dataProvider()
    line=QgsFeature()
    for f in layer.getFeatures(request):
        termino = QgsPoint(feat['shape_pt_lon'],feat['shape_pt_lat'])
        PointList.append(termino)
        line.setGeometry(QgsGeometry.fromPolyline(PointList))
        pr.addFeatures( [ line ] )
        v_layer.updateExtents()
        QgsProject.instance().addMapLayers([v_layer])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few logical errors in your code. Please see the updated code with comments for explanation:

```
layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName("shap")[0]
features = layer.getFeatures()
hodList=[]
for feat in features:
    ids=feat['shape_id']
    hodList.append(ids)
unikatniId=list(set(hodList))


v_layer = QgsVectorLayer("LineString?crs=epsg:4326", "line", "memory")
pr = v_layer.dataProvider()
## I do believe that you want to store resulting lines in one layer,
## so these lines should be moved from internal for loop


for i in unikatniId:
    expression = ('"shape_id" LIKE \'%s%s\''%(i,'%'))
    request = QgsFeatureRequest().setFilterExpression(expression)
    PointList = []

    line=QgsFeature()
    for f in layer.getFeatures(request):

        termino = QgsPoint(f['shape_pt_lon'],f['shape_pt_lat']) #I do understand that shape_pt_lon and shape_pt_lat are columns containing coordinates 
        ## definitely you want to use f rather then feat. 
        ## Feat was returning last scanned point,
        ## that is why you were getting empty lines
        ## (actually they were lines consisting of one point) 

        PointList.append(termino)

    line.setGeometry(QgsGeometry.fromPolyline(PointList))
    pr.addFeatures( [ line ] )
    ## indenting might be reason of logical errors.
    ## You probably want to add line only once for given unikatniId
    ## so take it outside of "f" loop

v_layer.updateExtents()
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayers([v_layer])
## And finally add shape to MapLayers, but only once
## (if you want to have one layer with resulting lines)
```

Comment: Thanks for editing my code.